# AVAudioRecorder record method fails in device but work in simulator

Tags: objective-c

i have an init as:

```
    bool b;
 NSLog(@"url");
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
NSLog(@"dizionario");
NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
     [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
     [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
     [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
     nil];

NSError *error; 

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:audioSettings error:&error];
NSLog(@"audio");
if (recorder) {
//NSLog(@"prepara");
[recorder prepareToRecord];
//NSLog(@"meter");
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
//NSLog(@"recorder");
b=[recorder record];
                    NSLog(@"%@",(b ? @"OK" : @"here it FAILS"));

} else {
NSLog(@"ERRORE:");
NSLog([error description]); 
}  
//NSLog(@"fine init");
```

as i use [recorder record] fails.
how can i know why this method fails?
how can i manage this problem?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

I too was having the problem where I could record in the simulator but not the device. Changing to using `NSTemporaryDirectory()` worked for me.

```
recordPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sound.m4a"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:recordPath];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup your AVAudioSession. 
Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676292/avaudiorecorder-wont-record-on-device) it can help you I think.

And don't forget to activate your AVAudioSession in your code if you use record and play in the same application.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar question, but found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676292/avaudiorecorder-wont-record-on-device), before posting it.  Can you write to "/dev/null" on the device?  is it a directory there?  Be sure to search the answers before posting questions :-(.

Comment: i had readed thet topic before asking. unfortunately... i have another application that make the same thing with the same instruction, and works well. so i thought that could be some conflict or something else...i'm trying to comment part of code, but till now unsuccessfully.

Comment: @sefiroths OK--you should include this info with your question.  I have actually had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861871/avaudiorecorder-preparetorecord-works-but-record-fails).  I suggest you think about what other audio stuff you are doing that might interfere...