# AVAudioRecorder prepareToRecord works, but record fails

Tags: avaudiorecorder

I just built and tested a basic AVAudioRecorder/AVAudioPlayer sound recorder and player. Eventually I got this working on the device, as well as the simulator.  My player/recorder code is in a single UIView subclass.  Unfortunately, when I copy the class into my main project, it no longer works (on the device--the simulator is fine).  `prepareToRecord` is working fine, but `record` isn't. Here is some code:

```
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];
        if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord]){
            audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
            if(![audioRecorder record])NSLog(@"recording failed!");
        }else {
            int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]); 
            NSLog(@"preparedToRecord=NO Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode); 
...
```

I get "recording failed". Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I've found the problem.  Elsewhere in my main project I use a Cocos2d "SimpleAudioEngine", which has its own [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].  My guess is that this somehow interferes with my audio session settings, for instance, this: [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];  Anyhow, when I remove my SimpleAudioEngine, my recorder/player works.  Of course that leaves me with another problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete solution was to move the `[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]` initialisation to before my own `AVAudioSession setCategory`. I think somewhere in `SimpleAudioEngine`, its doing a `setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`. Overriding this with my own `setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` later makes everything work.

Comment: Valid answer in iOS 17!